# Installing Pester on Windows 7

Tags: powershell, windows-7-x64, pester

I'm trying to run Pester tests on a Windows 7 machine. I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/12/get-started-with-pester-powershell-unit-testing-framework/), and I also installed PSGet and executed `Install-Module Pester`.

This works on both the Windows 7 machines I have. I can run the pester tests from an elevated PowerShell console.

I have a .cmd file which runs the Pester tests, but I'm unable to run it from an elevated command prompt. This works on one Windows 7 machine, but it doesn't work on another one.

I followed the same instructions to install Pester on both the machines. Please suggest what I might be missing.

On the machine that 'doesn't work':
When I run the Pester script from PowerShell, the `Invoke-Pester` works and the script runs as expected. But, when I try to run the .cmd file which points to the pester scripts, I get an error saying `Invoke-Pester` is not recognized as a cmdlet, function; which means, as far as I understood, Pester is not working from the command prompt.

On the machine that 'works':

I am able to run the Pester script from both PowerShell and command prompt windows. The script runs as expected.

Comment: Please elaborate on "works" and "doesn't work" - what happens exactly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Please show the content of your .cmd file and the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the particular laptop I was working on, had some permission issues (corporate issues), and I couldn't get the Pester scripts working from the command prompt.

Anyway, I moved on to another Windows 7 laptop and installed Pester using the following instructions:

- Download `PsGet.psm1` from https://github.com/psget/psget/
- Copy `PsGet.psm1` to your modules folder (e.g. Modules\PsGet)
- Start a new PowerShell session and import the Pester module using the commands below:

  `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Pester`

  `Import-Module PsGet`

  `Install-Module PsGet`

  `Import-Module Pester.psm1`

  `Install-Module Pester`
- Check the execution policy set on the computer with: `Get-ExecutionPolicy`. The output should be `Unrestricted`. Otherwise, run: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`